# Background Color on Row when selecting row React Table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I'm doing a custom table with React Table & Typescript and I did when selecting a row on a checkbox it must change the checkbox and update the background color for the ones that are selected.

The problem is when I select the row for the first time, it works as expected but then when I click it again it doesn't update the background color. I'm using the property of row.isSelected to put the background color.

```
<Tr
 {...row.getRowProps()}
 style={{
 backgroundColor: !row.isSelected ? "none" : "#E9D8FD",
}}
```

The list is being updated correctly but the background color doesn't.

I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

"none" is not a valid color. You may want to use "transparent" instead.

Comment: Thanks @cindy !!!